# What does numpy.corrcoef do?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

i have 2 arrays

```
nums1 = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
nums2 = numpy.array([5,4,3,2,1])
```

when i type

```
numpy.corrcoef(nums1)
numpy.corrcoef(nums2)
```

both times i got same result : 1.0

but when i try

```
numpy.corcoef(nums1,nums2)
```

result becomes more unclear

```
array([[ 1., -1.],
   [-1.,  1.]])
```

I tried to understand what does it do , but unfortunately my English skills are not enough for that , so i wonder if anyone can explain simply what it does.

Comment: Mark it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The function provides a correlation matrix.

When provided one vector (list), the matrix is 1x1, and the vector is perfectly correlated to itself.

When you supply your two vectors (lists), a 2x2 matrix is returned with -1 correlations for nums1 and nums2 and vice versa, and 1 correlations for each list to itself.